# Master Thesis about Heston vs. Duan option pricing model

Tags: options, volatility, garch, pricing, heston

I would like to write my master's thesis on volatility in option pricing. My idea was to compare the stochastic volatility model of Heston 1993 with the GARCH option pricing model of Duan 1995. For this I want to compare the pricing of S&P500 index options

I am in the process of familiarizing myself with the topic, but I have come across a few points that confuse me.

One is how to configure the two models so that I can compare them. As there are too many moving parts it is not clear why one or the other model "wins".

As I understand it, it only makes sense to compare the Q processes (risk neutral). However, I do not yet fully understand what lambda (price of volatility risk) takes on a value in the Q process.

I also have the general question of how far I can compare discrete and continuous time models.

It probably makes more sense to compare Heston and Nandi with Duan, but my question is whether I can also compare Heston and Duan.

Thanks for any help and feedback.

Comment: You write "*For this I want to compare the pricing of S&P500 index options*": if you want to price the index options in isolation, i.e. one at a time, then a stochastic vol model is not needed for that (you could just use a plain-vanilla Black-Scholes). The Heston model can capture the smile: so you could try to price collars and strangles, and see how the change in the smile affects the prices of the collars and strangles: you could compare how well the change in the smile is captured by Heston vs. Duan for example. But just pricing index options on their own is not a good topic.